# Why did Procrastitracker stop showing the details here?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a problem with [Procrastitracker](http://strlen.com/procrastitracker/)  -

[image]

Procrastitracker used to show the names of all the sites/apps, but it stop showing the details here?

Comment: ask their support for help

Comment: I got lucky, the author of software actually responded here,  :  )  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "expanded level" slider is all the way to the right, which means its trying to show a potentially really big tree. Maybe it is running out of memory to do so.

Simply bring this slider back to the left-most position, and see if that makes show the tree again.

If it still behaves wonky, feel free to send me your db.PT file, and I can debug it. It shouldn't really have a problem displaying 10 days worth of data.

(I'm the author of this software :)

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try this,  and let you know if that fixes it (on a different machine at the moment)

Comment: I looked, and I didn't see a db.PT file in the directory - [directory - image here ](http://i.imgur.com/xiyg8jH.png)

Comment: Look in the start menu, ProcrastiTracker -> Database files